# Filter values by hours in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have a date table:

[image]

I need to filter this by hours. last 4h 12h 24h etc.
Relative date only gives me days-weeks and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by creating 4 new custom columns with code:

```
DateTime.IsInPreviousNHours([LastTransactionDate],4)
```

Which gives me values if TRUE or FALSE and can filter by turning off FALSE values.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest work-around could be to create a binary FLAG in the back-end to identify record created in the last 4h.

Then, define a slicer in the front-end (visible or hidden) to visualize only those records relevant for you.

Comment: I have duplicated the date and transformed it to show hours only. Now I have a column with hours but I still can't filter it to show last hours etc, why has this simple thing made so hard in Power BI...

Comment: They enjoy not completing their work (i.e. only relative date filtering and not relative time). Why can't you create a flag to track whether the record was generated in the last hour? And then the user can filter on a slicer like 'Last Hour', 'Last 1/2 Hour', etc ?

Comment: Record generated date is different from the column that I need to filter. For example DB was updated 27.04.2020 12:34 but the column that I need to filter "LastTransacitonDate" has different values for each machine, some may have date 25.04 and some 27.04 etc.
So far I have tried to create a new measure:
`IfLast4 = 
VAR HourDiff =
    HOUR ( NOW () ) - HOUR ( MIN ( 'POS LaneCurrentState'[LastTransactionDate] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( HourDiff >= 0 && HourDiff <= 4; 1; 0 )`
This somewhat works but it filters only hours not dates now, it also shows me last 4hours in every day

Comment: If you need to only consider today's event, you could add a relative date filter for today. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: If i filter to show the latest day only ( relative date filter for today ) then I wouldn't get accurate results at times for example: 28.04.2020 0:00 - 03:59 and the difference goes even bigger with 12h, 24h and 48h. The data is set to refresh every 15 minutes. I'm now trying to figure out how to use "DateTime.IsInPreviousNHours" M code in power query to get the results I need.